# Anybody want to take over the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

Stack Exchange is discontinuing the community blogs.

Their default plan is to convert everything to static files and keep that up. That would mean that the current content would be available, but nobody could comment on it, nothing could be edited and nothing new could be posted.

If there's sufficient interest, it is possible to get a data dump to import into a blog hosted elsewhere.

Is anybody super interested in taking over the bicycles.se blog? Got lots of ideas for articles, time to write them, and strongly inclined to assist other members of our community in getting things posted?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we have sufficient interest in it -- we haven't used it in [nearly 2.5 years](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/). And it doesn't really advertise anywhere on the site. I had to search Google to find the URL.

But if anyone wants to maintain it, it might be better to have a personal blog instead and then link to it here, like what [computer science does](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22191/what-cs-blogs-should-everyone-read).

Comment: I agree. Wanted to check and make sure nobody was interested.